# How to merge two rows in the same dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame which contains two rows. The value in the column "ID" for both these rows is the same. How can I create a new data frame and bring all the values in both the rows into one row, but in separate columns?

For example, if in the input data frame, there is a column called "Amount" in both the rows, The new data frame should contain one-row with two different columns as Amount_1 and Amount_2.

groupby does not work as I do not want all the information in the same columns.

I can not merge, as this is not from two different data frames.

Turn:

```
+------+--------+----------+---------+
| ID   | Amount |Name      |State    |
|------|--------|----------+---------+
| 1    | 16     |A         |CA       |
| 2    | 32     |B         |GA       |
| 2    | 64     |C         |NY       |
+------+--------+----------+---------+
```

into:

```
+------+----------+----------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
| ID   | Amount_1 | Amount_2 |Name_1 | Name_2 | State_1 | State_2|
|------|----------|----------|-------+--------+---------+--------+
| 1    | 16       |          |A      |        | CA      |        |
| 2    | 32       | 64       |B      |C       | GA      | NY     |
+------+----------+----------+-------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Took the liberty to add a table with what I understood. Let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thank You, Eric. You are absolutely right. I am just waiting to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a column that will contain the column names of the new `DataFrame` by using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). After that, use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['amountnr'] = 'Amount_' + df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
df.pivot(index='ID', columns= 'amountnr', values='Amount')
#amountnr  Amount_1  Amount_2
#ID                          
#1             16.0       NaN
#2             32.0      64.0
```

#### Edit

With you new specifications, I feel you should really use a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), like so:

```
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
df.set_index(['ID', 'cumcount']).unstack()
#         Amount       Name      State     
#cumcount      1     2    1    2     1    2
#ID                                        
#1          16.0   NaN    A  NaN    CA  NaN
#2          32.0  64.0    B    C    GA   NY
```

If you insist, you can later always join the columns of your MultiIndex:

```
df2.columns = ['_'.join([coltype, str(count)]) for coltype, count in df2.columns.values]
```

Comment: Thank You, Jondie. But, what if there are more columns like Amount (say name, number, address) and I want those details also to be formed as more columns similar to Amount_1 and Amount_2

Comment: Could you please edit the example DataFrames in your question so that it's clear what input and desired output is?

Comment: Edited. Please check. I would need the result in that format.